# Beta font issue - descender is hidden by OP username

Tags: bug, comments, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When the OP’s username appears directly below code in a comment, underscores are not visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114109/when-the-ops-username-appears-directly-below-code-in-a-comment-underscores-are)

In the comments to a question, the [descenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) are partially cutoff by the OP's username.  Specifically, the g's in "googling" are partially obscured.  I noticed it on a [beta site](http://chess.stackexchange.com) in [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/1419/12).

[image: The gees in googling are cutoff]

I'm using Chrome on Windows XP, but it was the same in Firefox and on my Windows 7 box as well.

Comment: (the other post points out a more specific case, but the overall problem is the same)

Comment: @TimStone I looked for duplicates but didn't see that one.  Definitely looks like the same issue (`line-height: 17px` (on the `comment-copy span`) hides the bottom of the descender, `line-height: 18px` shows it)

Comment: ggggggggggg just a silly example comment so that it shows up here as well (no navigation required!)

Comment: `^^^^^^^^^^^---` Looks OK to me, in IE8 and FireFox.  In fact, [this](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1419/is-there-an-online-chess-game-or-app-that-allows-for-custom-setup-of-pieces) looks OK to me as well.  Ah, the [dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114109/when-the-ops-username-appears-directly-below-code-in-a-comment-underscores-are) says the same thing.  Must be a problem specific to Chrome.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Looks fine in Chrome on OSX.  Specific to Chrome + Windows.