# Why don't you like my "g"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, design

When a comment on [a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2237019) is long enough to be on two lines, part of the descender of the first line is being eaten by the line beneath.

> [image: Pixel overflow!]

I'm on Chrome 27.0.1453.94 m and Windows 7 if it's relevant.

You can see what is happening when selecting the text:

[image: selected]

Comment: Viewing on Safari, Firefox and Chrome on Mac I am able to see the bottom of the `g`s

Comment: [Looks fine for me on Safari (Mac)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Umw.png)

Comment: Looks fine on Mobile Safari 6.0.

Comment: Similar to [Background in OP's user name can obscure text in multiline comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114109), this is likely specific to Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Happens on my Chrome 27.0.1453.94  on Windows 8

Comment: Very nice demonstration @Oded!

Comment: Betting on `line-height` of that `span`

Comment: Why no shark? It's not like we [hate fun here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)... :P

Comment: @Luke looks like Peter just doesn't like sharks (childhood trauma maybe? ;))

Comment: Are you using zoom in chrome, by any chance? I've had similar issues because of that with otherwise nicely-looking-g's on other sites.

Comment: @bobobobo you nailed it! The current line height is 1.4 (em) so without any line height specified it look [much worse](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8WMy.png) while line height of 1.5 [save the day](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k8X8Y.png) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll repost my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182985/213495) from a [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182916/213495) here (since my [question with more details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182980/213495) is <del>probably soon to be</del> closed) as suggestion for quick/possible fixes.

I've just ran into a [Suggested Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/267410/revisions) which present the same issue. The comment is barely readable, given that the 2nd (and subsequent) lines overlap half of the previous. This phenomenon also happens in the [individual revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/267410/4) page.

---

The issue seems to be the CSS applied to the `body` element: `line-height: 1;`.

Disabling/removing this entry makes the comment expand properly (along with several other element sizing on the page). Here's a screenshot showing the correct-looking comment:

[image: Screenshot showing the proper look]

---

An alternative solution (so as to not mess with the rest of the design) is to add `line-height: 1.4em;` to the `revision-comment` CSS class.

Comment: That comment doesn’t look correct-looking.

Comment: To which comment are you referring?

Comment: The comment in your screenshot that you said was correct-looking. The “g”s are still cut off…?

Comment: You're right; I hadn't noticed that detail. This was fixed about three months ago, though.