# Multi-line flag messages for "other" flags overlap in the flagged posts list

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flags

[Not appreciating the letter 'g' is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182728/why-dont-you-like-my-g) is of course a problem. And I'm glad this has been resolved. Whether I appreciate the solution however, I'm not certain. ;)

> [image]

It now seems the lines are overlapping completely in the Flagged Posts list for the "other" flags with a description. Of course this is consistent, but I'm not sure it's a great feature. :)

I'm on Chrome Version 27.0.1453.94 m, on Windows 7 if it matters. I have no ad-ons or user scripts installed. The same effect shows on

- Stack Overflow
- Meta Stack Overflow
- Gamedev SE
- Programmers SE

On other accounts I don't have multi-line flag messages, but I would assume the result to be the same.

Updating to Version 27.0.1453.110 m just now, the problem remains.

Comment: Try using a smaller font in your browser ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer Or maybe it's a hint and I should just type less....

Comment: You do realize we are special casing for you?

Comment: That would be only a partial workaround, though. Sometimes you _need_ to type more for an "other" flag. A small enough font works for all lengths.

Comment: @Oded I had that suspicion when I couldn't disable the big orange banner saying "We don't like you. We really really don't like you" at the top of my screen.

Comment: The `g` problem also happens here on Bart's comment (but only on small scale). Note the grey highlight on the name of the author and `big`. (I am on Firefox 21 btw)

Comment: The bottom line just gets hungry. You should feed it more often.

Comment: @Bart, on what site did you see this?  I just checked the SO flags queue and found several multi-line comments that looked as they should, using Chrome 27.0.1453.94 m on Windows 7.

Comment: @BenCollins On Meta and SO proper, as well as the Gamedev SE and Programmers SE. My other accounts don't have multi-line flag messages. I see the same at home and at work (Both on Windows 7). I'm running no ad-ons or user scripts. Chrome just updated to Version 27.0.1453.110 m for  me, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is resolved.  Obviously, you picked up on the fact that line-height wasn't being set sensibly.  It is now, and it should give more consistent results across browser/os combinations.

Comment: Yep, looking good now. Thanks for that. :)

Comment: I see this still occurring on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9134/revisions) and [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/388242/revisions?page=2), though the severity has been reduced to the level of [unpopular Gs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182728/why-dont-you-like-my-g?lq=1). Chrome 27.0.1453.110m on WinXP, no scripts or extensions.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName sorry.  I don't see it (Chrome on Windows).

Answer (score 5):

I'll post an answer here (since my [question with more details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182980/213495) is <del>probably soon to be</del> closed) as suggestion for quick/possible fixes.

I've just ran into a [Suggested Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/267410/revisions) which present the same issue. The comment is barely readable, given that the 2nd (and subsequent) lines overlap half of the previous. This phenomenon also happens in the [individual revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/267410/4) page.

---

The issue seems to be the CSS applied to the `body` element: `line-height: 1;`.

Disabling/removing this entry makes the comment expand properly (along with several other element sizing on the page). Here's a screenshot showing the correct-looking comment:

[image: Screenshot showing the proper look]

---

An alternative solution (so as to not mess with the rest of the design) is to add `line-height: 1.4em;` to the `revision-comment` CSS class.