# Really long Suggested Edit comment breaks into more than two lines, and the text overlaps

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, design

I've just ran into a [Suggested Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/267410/revisions) which has a really long comment. The issue is that the comment is barely readable, given that the 2nd (and subsequent) lines overlap half of the previous. This phenomenon also happens in the [individual revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/267410/4) page.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing the overlapping text]

---

The issue seems to be the CSS applied to the `body` element: `line-height: 1;`.

Disabling this entry makes the comment expand properly (along with several other sizing on the page). Here's a screenshot showing the correct-looking comment:

[image: Screenshot showing the proper look]

---

An alternative solution (so as to not mess with the rest of the design) is to add `line-height: 1.4em;` to the `revision-comment` CSS class.

Comment: I see it.  It seems related somehow to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182916/why-dont-you-like-any-of-my-characters and possibly http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182728/why-dont-you-like-my-g, but this one actually manifests more broadly than the others.

Comment: Wow. By the life of me, the title of those questions doesn't even lead to a proper understanding. I guess I can delete my question then.

Comment: @Jesse Just leave it be. It does no harm and provides additional insights. Or perhaps you can make it an answer to one of the duplicates, stating you have found another location with the same issue and what you narrowed it down to.

Comment: @Bart Yup, just finished doing that.