# Make links in comments immune to being hidden by username

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface, hyperlinks, design

In [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201772/add-high-resolution-graphics-and-or-svg-icons#comment640660_201772), there is a clickable link (the word `here`); however, because of the distance between the word and the dotted underline, it is actually covered by the grey box surrounding the author's name. The underline is really the only visual cue we have that it is a link, because there is *no* color difference between normal text and hyperlinks on meta.

> [image]

In this case, this is just bad luck, and it doesn't happen that often, but it caused some confusion as you can see from the subsequent comments. Can we fix this such that either (or both):

- the line-height or padding is adjusted so the underline is always visible
- the color for links is changed so that they are more obvious ([I've also asked for this on dba.se](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/974/visited-links-in-our-meta-are-almost-invisible), but not action yet)

**P.S. if you don't see the word "here" circled in red in the image above, please [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VyAh.png) and then hit Ctrl+Refresh. There is some caching issue with the image that leads to a lower-quality and degraded sample.**

Comment: To the first point: [Background in OP's user name can obscure text in multiline comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114109)

Comment: [Not *quite* an issue on IE 10.0.9200 on Win RT.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X94WB.png)

Comment: +1 For the hand drawn circle and also because I was the victim of that comment's link.

Comment: I am not very sure how much the line height or padding of the name can be adjusted. To see the full overlap of the link in question, navigate to the [question with that comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201772/add-high-resolution-graphics-and-or-svg-icons#comment640660_201772), and in the URL type `javascript:` then paste `$('.comment-copy').eq(1).css({zIndex:1,position:'relative'});` and you will see the overlap with the link's underline.

Comment: @TravisJ: That works (but I'm also out of comment votes for the day).

Comment: Haha, that's me :D

Comment: Tis fine on Debian 7 (wheezy) Iceweasel 17.0.9. Can see the underline as with @michaelb958's link. It is close but still visible. and defo +1 for freehand text, circle AND a made up word! ;)

Comment: @michaelb958 **WHY** IE?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Because Surface RT (i.e. crippled).

Answer (score 5):

I think [@Aaron Bertrand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/165455/aaron-bertrand) is correct in that the padding of the name can be changed to fix this.

An edit can be made to the existing rule. The top padding could be set to 0 from this rule, saving two characters of space ("px").

```
a.comment-user.owner {
 padding: 0 5px 2px 5px;
}
```

It is currently `padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;`

Comment: Would using z-index not solve the problem?

Comment: @AnthimosKouroutsidis - The suggestion to use the z-index would also be a solution, however it would require a new rule and I know they are very strict about the amount of css they use.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is solved since [The Great Split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014) :)

> [image]